# jQuery Pull Entire DIV into String Variable?

Tags: jquery, html, string, variables

Howdy, I'm a little confused about how to work with *this* in jQuery (1.5.2).

For a nested comment thread I'm navigating to a parent comment's reply link. I'm attempting to capture it, manipulate the string, and spit it back out elsewhere on the page.

This is how I'm traversing the tree to the target:
`$('.commentlist > li > div .reply').each(function() {`

At this point I can gobble up this entire div by using `var reply = this;` -- and that works great if I was simply cloning it -- but I honestly don't know how to take that array of information and pluck *just* the complete HTML string out of it.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

Hi again. The goal is to copy this fellow into a simple string variable for each match:

`<div class="reply">

 <a class="comment-reply-link" href="http://someurl/foo/testing-post-four/?replytocom=5#respond" onclick='return addComment.moveForm("comment-5", "5", "respond", "8")'>Reply</a>

</div>`

Using `alert ($(this).html());` only returns the inner anchor tag & contents, not the div wrapper. Thoughts?

Comment: var reply = $(this).html(); dont know which array? may be this would be help full array.join(separator);

Comment: You know, that's exactly what I tried, but I'm getting the _contents_ of the DIV without the wrapping DIV tags! `alert ($(this).html());`

Comment: A little new to how to clarify things for the big brains in here! Will edit the question above with further details.

Comment: next time try and abstract the problem from your particular implementation - the each does not matter. you just need to know how to get the complete HTML of a particular selector/jquery dom object

Comment: I'm wondering if it would just be simpler to hardcode in the outer divs. `$(this).html()` would work with that. Being a jQuery newbie I thought I was overlooking something silly. Seems it's more complicated.

Comment: Thanks all for your thoughts. I'm going to concede this one and just go with the manual div creation. [The Results](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-comment-reply-button-after-every-comment-in-2-levels-threads?replies=5#post-2049970).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could clone it into another `<div>` and then call `html()` on that:

```
var html = $('<div/>').append($(this).clone()).html();
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/59zwr/1/

Comment: Interesting, but I'd rather just hard code the div's in there before going for this. Thank you very much for the jsfiddle.net example! Useful.

Comment: @mu: How can I iterate over each "p" tag inside it? I have a requirement where I need to get contents of a div and find all the anchor tags and replace it's value, if satisfies a condition

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: something like `$(html).find('p').each(function() {...})` perhaps? Hard to say without more detail.

Comment: @mu: Thanks for your response, i got it answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407290/find-a-pattern-in-dom-and-replace-its-content-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

Finally got it working..!! the simplest way !!
 HTML Code

```
<div class="extra-div">
    <div class="div-to-pull-in-variable">
     // Your Content Here
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Code

```
    $(function() {
        var completeDiv = $('.extra-div').html();
        alert(completeDiv); 
       })
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the parent...

```
<div class='a'>
    blah
</div>
```

....

`alert(jQuery('.a').parent().html())`

Comment: Hummm, `$(this).parent().html()` correctly gives me the contents of the parent one level higher, not the one I'm trying to copy into a string. `$(this).html()` is just the contents of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You could do...

```
$('body *').each(function() {
   var outerHtml = $('<div />').html(this).html();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BWG6/).

Also note that IE has a native `outerHTML` property.

Comment: But this will lose any attributes that `this` has.

Comment: @mu Oh yeah, didn't think of that :P I'll make a new version.

Answer (score 0):

Hey dude, is this what you were trying to do? Your question was a little vague, so I made a few assumptions. Let me know if this is not what you were wanting to be able to manipulate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="one"   class="reply"><a href="#">reply link</a></div>
    <div id="two"   class="reply"><a href="#">reply link</a></div>
    <div id="three" class="reply"><a href="#">reply link</a></div>
    <div id="four"  class="reply"><a href="#">reply link</a></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.reply').each(function(n){
            var reply = this;
            // You can get attributes, classes, etc. like this
            console.log('ID of this div is: ' + $(reply).attr('id'));
            // You can change them like this
            $(reply).attr('id', n + 1)
            console.log('The new ID of this div is: ' + $(reply).attr('id'));

        }); 
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried the code above? As far as I can see, its doing what you need. If, in the `.each()` callback, you used `console.log(reply);`, you'll see its outputting the entire div, contents and all.

Comment: Howdy. I thought `console.log` was a Firebug thing?

Comment: `console.log()` is supported in other situations as well (Chrome's console, for example). Regardless, its simply meant to illustrate the changes. Is in no way necessary to make this work.

You may be getting a little caught up in some of the particulars and missing the bigger picture. @user406905's comment on your original question is a wise observation. If you can abstract the problem a little more generally and not get stuck on small details in examples, you'll have an easier time using the answers provided.