# Find a pattern in DOM and replace it's content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div containing elements something like below

```
<input type="hidden" name="subscribe_message" value="Success"/>
<div class="titleBlue">Alerts</div>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td align="LEFT" height="35">
<tr>
<td><a style="cursor:hand;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank" href="https://abc.global.com/kb/solution/21/Pages/136776.aspx">ab1</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a style="cursor:hand;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank" href="https://abc.global.com/kb/solution/21/Pages/136775.aspx">ab2</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a style="cursor:hand;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank" href="https://abc.global.com/kb/solution/21/Pages/136774.aspx">ab3</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td><a href='#' onClick="javascript:window.open('https://my-prod.global.com/gmm2/kb/dlink.do?externalId=<a style="cursor:hand;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank" href="https://abc.global.com/kb/solution/20/Pages/157468.aspx">157468 </a></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a style="cursor:hand;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank" href="https://abc.global.com/kb/solution/20/Pages/147468.aspx">147468 </a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need a way to find all `abc.global.com` within anchor tag and replace with `cab.global.com` and append **?source=abc** in the same link.

So how can I traverse through each a tag under div containing id="clicker" and replace the anchor href value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // loop over all links inside the table
    $("a", "#clicker").each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if(href.indexOf("abc.global.com") >= 0){
            // replace domain
            href = href.replace("abc.global.com", 'cab.global.com');
            // append source param
            href += "?source=abc";
            $(this).attr('href', href);
        }  
    });
});​
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yp6x/1/)

Comment: Everyone gave the correct answer, but since you even gave me a solution for appending **?source=abc** so, accepted your solution as answer

Comment: Just hardcoding the `?source=abc` part would fail where the source url already has the `?` or `#` parts. I've added the functionality there in case you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( 'div#clicker a' ).each(function(o){
   var _anchor = $(this).attr('href');

   if(_anchor.indexOf( 'abc.global.com' )!=-1) {
      _anchor = _anchor.replace( 'abc.global.com', 'cba.global.com' );
      _anchor = modify( _anchor );
      $(this).attr('href',_anchor);
   }
});

function modify( anchor ) {
    if( anchor.indexOf( '?' ) != -1 ) {
        anchor = anchor.replace( anchor.indexOf( '?' ), '?source=abc&' );
    } else if( anchor.indexOf( '#' ) != -1 ) {
        anchor = anchor.replace( anchor.indexOf( '#' ), '?source=abc#' );
    } else {
        anchor += '?source=abc';
    }

    return anchor;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Changed. Earlier too, it wouldn't have been an error, just that the `replace` thing would run on every matching entity. Anyway, an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to simply loop through every  tag on the whole website you can use

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

to get a list of all of them.
Then just loop through them and change href where appropriate

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    if (links[i].href.search("abc.global.com") != -1)
    {
        links[i].href.replace("abc.global.com", "cab.global.com");
        links[i].href += "?source=abc";
    }
}
```

You might want to temporarily save href in a variable to increase performance and maybe add a few safety checks.

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/imowoh/4/edit)**

```
$('a[href*=abc]').each(function(){
    return this.href = this.href.replace('abc', 'cab')+'?source=abc';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a').each(function(a){
if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().indexOf("abc.global.com") >= 0){

$(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('abc.global.com','cab.global.com'));
$(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') + '?source=abc')
    }
});
```

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/MgsrV/